# UK: What information are the police legally required to collect when going door-to-door, and why?

Tags: united-kingdom, privacy, police, data-protection, personal-information

A few days ago, a police officer knocked on my door in the evening and asked whether I had noticed any disturbances in my street earlier in the day - he said it was in relation to reports that they'd had, and were investigating.

I informed him that I hadn't noticed anything, and he then asked whether I had been at home at the time of the disturbance, and what I was doing at that time, as well as taking my name and date of birth.

What are the reasons/ legal requirements that the police might need my personal information, given that I had not been able to provide any further information/ witness testimony to the incident that they were investigating?

I would understand the need to collect it had I been able to provide any further information regarding the incident, or been asked to provide a witness statement, but given I hadn't been able to, what would the legal reasons be for them to collect/ hold this information?

Comment: This is why you never talk to police.

Comment: There doesn't need to be a legal reason for anyone to ask you a question.  Your neighbour could've come up to your door and asked you the same questions just out of idle curiosity.

Comment: @Studoku Never? The last time I had a door-to-door inquiry, they were investigating a local murder where the firearm used had been identified. I had recently bought my house from someone who had a license for the same type of firearm. I'm sure if I had told them I had no information at all about the guy who had sold me the house a couple of weeks before, and refused to give them any form of identification, they would have just said "aw, shucks, that was a waste of a visit" and that would have been the end of it .... not.

Comment: @alephzero My mistake. The fact that the police strongarm people into talking is a great reason to talk to them... not.

Comment: @RossRidge Ha, yep, ok, fair enough. I think the context of the question as described in my post frames my query fairly clearly though - why would the police need my personal information, given that I was not able to provide any information to assist their enquiry. The point is not about them asking the question, it's about what legal reasons they would have to need/ hold the information they were asking for.

Comment: @studoku I appreciate that there can be cases of improper conduct/ abuse of a position of authority, etc within the police, but I'd hardly call asking a question 'strongarming'. If everyone adopted the mindset of 'never talking to police', it would make their job much harder. As a member of the public, I would like to help an investigation when called upon if I possibly can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**What are the reasons/ legal requirements that the police might need my personal information, given that I had not been able to provide any further information/ witness testimony to the incident that they were investigating?**

The police in [england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales) have a duty to undertake reasonable lines of enquiry and to carry out a proportionate investigation in to allegations of crime.

No-one is legally obliged to answer [house to house](https://www.app.college.police.uk/app-content/investigations/investigative-strategies/house-to-house-enquiries/#providing-reassurance) questions but, notwithstanding the honesty and integrity of the majority of members of the public, any information held by the police may need to be corroborated to identify or eliminate suspects, witnesses, evidential opportunities or other lines of enquiry.

Also, if it is established that someone has no information that may assist the investigation this is recorded to prevent duplication of effort thus enabling the police to focus their resources accordingly.

All the while complying with the relevant privacy and data retention legislation.

Comment: Notably, the fact that OP *didn't hear anything* at the prescribed time is also a form of evidence. For example, if one neighbour had reported another neighbour for (supposedly) breaching a noise protection order.